# Loop through directories and rsync contents

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync

I'm looking to rsync only specific files and directories from a cpanel backup to a remote server.

The basic structure is:

```
/backup/cpbackup/daily/USERNAME
```

from within USERNAME directory I want to backup

```
../USERNAME/mysql/USERNAME.sql
```

and also a folder (containing files and subfolders)

```
../USERNAME/homedir/siteassets
```

so I end up on my remote server with:

```
/USERNAME/mysql/USERNAME.sql
/USERNAME/homedir/siteassets
```

I could use wildcards

```
rsync /backup/cpbackup/daily/*/mysql/*.sql  user@remote.ip.address:servername/
```

but this won't give me the USERNAME folder remotely and will mean all the files end up getting merged. I assume this is possible by iterating through folders with bash or something like tht but thats not my strong point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered it myself:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/backup/cpbackup/daily"

for dir in `ls "$src/"`
do
  if [ -d "$src/$dir" ]; then

        # look for mysql directory      
        mypath="$src/$dir/mysql"
        if [ -d $mypath ]; then
                mysqlfile=$mypath/$dir".sql"
                rsync -vau --progress --stats --rsh=ssh $mysqlfile user@remote.ip.address.net:servername/$dir
        fi

        # look for images directory      
        impath="$src/$dir/homedir/siteassets"
        if [ -d $impath ]; then
                rsync -vau --progress --stats --rsh=ssh $impath user@remote.ip.address.net:servername/$dir
        fi

  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

rsync has '--include-from' and '--exclude-from' parameters. This let you define white and black lists in a separate file. Maybe this can make the solution more simple.